# How to read/write to .yml files in minecraft plugin?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

So I want to make a .yml file which stores all the players that are being trolled by a command (e.g. /toggleblind Gustav_G). It should look like this:

```
2aed-6cdff32-1abaef9-de85f4a-ec66b7:
    - name: Gustav_G
    trolls:
      - SLOW
      - BLINDNESS
2aed-6ca4532-1acf4f9-debb5fa-eaf2b7:
    - name: Marvin_M
    trolls:
      - NOPICKAXE
      - NOJUMP
```

I have already created a playerDataFile object through which i can access the file:

```
public abstract class AbstractFile {
    protected Main main;
    private File file;
    protected FileConfiguration config;
    
    public AbstractFile(Main main, String fileName)
    {
        this.main = main;
        this.file = new File(main.getDataFolder(), fileName);
        if(!file.exists())
        {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
        }
        this.config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);
    }
    public void save()
    {
        try {
            config.save(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

and

```
public class PlayerDataFile extends AbstractFile{

    public PlayerDataFile(Main main) {
        super(main, "playerdata.yml");
    }
    
    
    public FileConfiguration get()
    {
        return config;
    }
    
}
```

My question is how do I add a player to this file, how do I check if he is already in that file, how can I see which trolls he has and how to check if he has a specific troll, how to remove a troll from a player in that file etc.
I did a lot of research but I got frustrated to try everything out because I have to restart the server everytime I edit the plugin...

Comment: As a suggestion, unless you create a new PlayerDataFile for every time you wish to read tha YAML (which I don't recommend neither), you shouldn't place the file load on the constructor. This will lead to read the file once, and never get the updates if something changed on it. The file reading should be placed in another method, like f.e `reloadFile`. You could have a cached version of the YAML stored in that class, and check if changes were made on the file (by looking at the last modified time of the file, for example). If you notice changes are made, reload it. If not, use the cached file.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a way to reload the cached data in the file, this can be easily done with the following code:

```
this.config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);
```

Try using that inside a method like this:

```
public void reloadConfig(){
    this.config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);
}
```

But it would be a waste of resources reloading the file every X time, so I recommend you to first create a List or a Map to store the temporary data, and before the plugin is disabled save the temp data in the config file, and when is loaded load the config file in the Map or List. But you should mainly edit the cached version of the config.